# PHP variable pass through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have PulsePro as CMS used. The template is on PHP, but the include parts are in HTML. The php mailer contains an Ajax Script, which I have implemented in the layout.php file. I have some different forms with different receiver email addys. Now, I want to define a variable for following string. This variable it will taken from the different include parts, e.g.

Here the link in the include files.

```
<?php $variable ="ajax1.php"; ?>
```

This is the ajax code in the layout.php file:

```
ajaxSubmit = function(){
            var frmData = $("#ifgForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                **url: "/includes/ajax.php", This is the original part, but here should be the variable
                data:     frmData,
                type:     "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    $("#f1_upload_process").hide();
                    $(".event-submit-btn").show();
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please be clearer about what you're trying to do. The AJAX code does't belong in a PHP file.

Comment: If your ajaxSubmit is on the current page *(not linked/included)* you should be able to `url:'<?php echo $variable;?>',` but if this function is in an external javascript file, you can assign the echo to a new variable *above/before* this function is included and must be done on the current page. `var AjaxUrl= '<?php echo $variable;?>'; `  then use the varaible in you function `url: AjaxUrl,`

Answer (score 0):

You can output the string inside ifgForm like this

```
<form id="ifgForm">
   <!-- [....] -->
   <input type="hidden" value="<?=$variable?>" name="variable" id="variable"> 
   <!-- [....] -->    
</form>
```

So u can find in the new variable field with other form fields data

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And in the function I paste [url:'<?php echo $variable;?>',] ?

Comment: OK thanks it works now. I took [url:'<?php echo $variable;?>',] in the function and in the include file with the form I paste the variable [<? $variable='include/ajax.php' ?>] and it works. thanks a lot!!!